# How to create a custom video seek bar in android?

Tags: android

I am creating a video trimmer app in android and i need the below information.

Should i use seekbar or rangeSlider component for selecting the range of the video to trim?

How do i customize the seekbar or range slider to should thumbnails?

How do i show the progress of the video being played within the selected range?

In summary how do i achieve as shown in the below screenshot.

[image]

Comment: Check this: https://github.com/HemendraGangwar/VideoTrimmingLikeWhatsapp

Answer (score 1):

Include the library as local library project.

```
 dependencies {
   implementation 'com.github.a914-gowtham:android-video-trimmer:1.7.0'
}
```

Add to project's root build.gradle file:

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
    }
}
```

Create a global variable for ActivityResultLauncher

```
ActivityResultLauncher<Intent> startForResult = registerForActivityResult(
            new ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult(),
            result -> {
                if (result.getResultCode() == Activity.RESULT_OK &&
                        result.getData() != null) {
                    Uri uri = Uri.parse(TrimVideo.getTrimmedVideoPath(result.getData()));
                    Log.d(TAG, "Trimmed path:: " + uri);
                   
                } else
                    LogMessage.v("videoTrimResultLauncher data is null");
            });
```

Add the code for opening Main Activity.

TrimVideo.activity(String.valueOf(videoUri))

```
//        .setCompressOption(new CompressOption()) 
//empty constructor for default compress option
          .setHideSeekBar(true)
          .start(this,startForResult);
```

Hide Player Seekbar:

```
.setHideSeekBar(true) //default value is false
```

Comment: Probably i would add the library and implement it, but would to know what how it is implemented in the library so that i can customize it as per my requirement.

Comment: You can check there code and get the idea but instead of doing that just add the libray and customize as per ur requirements as they provide alots of customization options...